# Casting Int to CMAttachmentMode

Tags: ios, swift, casting

I keep getting the error "Int not convertible to CMAttachmentMode". I'm not sure how I'm supposed to cast this variable in order to get it to work in my CFDictionaryRef. If someone could explain, I would appreciate it. Thanks!

```
var attachmentMode = kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate as CMAttachmentMode
var attachments:CFDictionaryRef = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, attachmentMode)
```

Comment: What is the type of kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate?

Comment: apple documentation says that kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate is type Int and that CMAttachmentMode's typealias is UInt32

Comment: I think I got it. I should've been casting it as UInt32(kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate). Stupid mistake. Thanks!

Comment: You could also try the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var attachmentMode = CMAttachmentMode(kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate)
var attachments:CFDictionaryRef = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, attachmentMode)
```